# getView() returns null

Tags: android, android-fragments

I basicall have an `AsyncTask` (run from main `Activity`) that populates a `ViewPager` inside a fragment. I'm inflating an xml layout file to populate the `ViewPager`.

The problem is that I can't get pointers to the views inside the layout (imageview, textview) so that I can change then at runtime. I know it's probably because `getView()` returns `null`. I've read that it's probably because `onCreateView()` hasn't been called, yet. Anybody know what I can do to solve this?

---

My code's a bit of a mess right now.

Here's a simpler explanation to what I'm doing:

1. MainActivity Asynctask populates a database and sends pointer to Fragment. Something like SendToFragement(db);
2. The Fragment method ReceiveFromActivity(db) receives db pointer and populates the ViewPager.

It works fine if I'm just creating TextViews, setting text, and adding TextViews to the Viewpager. But, of course, I want to make it look better so I've inflated an xml layout. The problem is that I can't change the contents of the xml layout because `getView()` is returning `NULL` so `getView().findViewById()` doesn't work.

Comment: How about some code, so we can point out where your problem is, and propose a fix.

Comment: You can't do work on the UI thread from the `doInBackground()`-method. Use the [`onProgressUpdate()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onProgressUpdate%28Progress...%29) to show results on the UI.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Depending on the implementation of your PagerAdapter, it is possible that a Fragment no longer in view will have their `View` destroyed in order to free up resources. As such, there's no need to update the `View` because it will be created again in `onCreateView()` with the updated information.  `getView()` will return a view in between calls to `onCreateView()` and `onDestroyView()`. Outside of that, the `Fragment` can still exist in memory, but not attached to any `View`, thus `getView()` will return `null`.

So basically,

```
View fragmentView = getView();
if(fragmentView != null) {
  // we are in view or at least exist. Update the elements.
}
// Else don't worry about it. Just update the data.
```

Comment: That's weird. I tried this
`View fragmentView = getView();
if(fragmentView != null) {ImageView img = (ImageView) fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    img.setImageResource(R.drawable.gasguy);}` 
but I'm still getting a NULL pointer exemption.

Comment: The if-statement is true if fragmentView is null.  Try `!=` instead.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `(fragmentView != null)`

Comment: Is it not finding "R.id.imageView1"?

Comment: At this point, I don't know what's happening. LOL. But I tried this `View fragmentView = getView().findViewById(R.id.imageView1); if(fragmentView != null) { ImageView img = (ImageView) fragmentView; img.setImageResource(R.drawable.gasguy);}` and it works. Could you enlighten me, please.

Comment: It's not finding `R.id.imageView`, so it skips the if-statement and your image gets updated in `onCreateView()` when the user swipes to the fragment. That's at least the first thing that comes to mind.

Comment: If you're calling `getView()` outside your fragment class that has the View, then it could be you're getting the wrong View.

Comment: These fragments are such a pain. Anyway, thank you for your help.